# gitlab doesn't send mails (queue still growing)

Tags: git, email, gitlab

I do setup my second GitLab Server. I love that tool :)

But I actually got an problem, wich I had in first setup too, but was able to fix it. Today I'am not. I'am searching now for hours.

GitLab is running. Thats good.
I can create an new User. Thats good.
But the Mail won't be send. That's actually not so good.

in "GITLABURL/admin/background_jobs" sidekiq is "inactiv" and the default-queue has an size of "2".
Two entrys like:

```
Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer   ["---\n- !ruby/class 'Notify'\n- :new_user_email\n- - 9\n - XYZ\n"]
```

I actually did an manually call to sendmail, for sending an mail. That succeed.

application.log, sidekiq.log, production.log, mail.log, mail.info, mail.warn, mail.err and exims mainlog got no infos.
Where can I search to find the problem?

I read about running

```
sudo -u git bundle exec rake environment resque:work QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production BACKGROUND=yes
```

manually, but that doesnt work

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'resque:default'
```

Please, if someone got any ideas, write me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Debian 7, GitLab 6.4.3, Shell 1.8.0, API v3, Ruby 2.0.0p353, Rails 4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

GitLab changed from Resque to Sidekiq for processing background jobs in 4.1. You can run Sidekiq manually like so:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q post_receive,mailer,system_hook,project_web_hook,common,default,gitlab_shell
```

Sidekiq should be started automatically with the GitLab web application if you're using the [init scripts](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/support/init.d/gitlab), which should be installed as part of the [installation process](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#install-init-script). If you did, check the output of `sudo /etc/init.d/gitlab start` to see why it's not starting properly.

Comment: Sidekiq was started, that was the confusing fact... I now did re-setup the whole server. Its working now. May I did something wrong through the setup.... Thanks for your response, may it help someone else

Answer (score 1):

It's because Sidekiq 2.17.8 won't handle requests separated by comma...

You can run `sidekiq` manually, replacing `,` with `-q`

```
bundle exec sidekiq -q post_receive -q mailer  -q system_hook -q project_web_hook -q common -q default -q gitlab_shell
```

or change your daemon.

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/init/systemd

I've just changed one line in file

`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gitlab-sidekiq.service`

from:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bundle exec "sidekiq -q post_receive,mailer,system_hook,project_web_hook,gitlab_shell,commo    n,default -e production -L /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq.log >> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq.log 2>&1"
```

to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bundle exec "sidekiq -q post_receive -q mailer -q system_hook -q project_web_hook -q gitlab_    shell -q common -q default -e production -L /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq.log >> /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq.log 2>&1"
```

And it works